# rostopic:command not found error-- turtlebot fuerte workstation pc

Tags: turtlebot, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently upgraded from ros electric to fuerte on the turtlebot 1. Installed everything smoothly on the turtlebot pc and the workstation pc. However when running the network test on both pc's, I get the error on the workstation pc when running the

```
rostopic list 
rostopic: command not found
```

what should be the problem? I installed the full desktop version of fuerte on both pcs.
I am using Ubuntu 12.04 on both pcs.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63590/rostopic:command-not-found-error---turtlebot-fuerte-workstation-pc/) by [Vegeta](https://answers.ros.org/users/2476/vegeta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 340 on 2013-05-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did u follow the complete tutorial?? You have to make some changes in .bashrc file so that all ros commands are recognized. Following the instructions mentioned on this page and first tutorial should do the trick.

http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu

---

Originally posted by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) with karma: 1610 on 2013-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1